# how to remove padding from container-fluid without causing horizontal scroll bars to appear in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The bootstrap class container-fluid gives a padding of 15px to the left and right of everything in it. When I create another class to remove the padding left and right the container-fluid gives, I get a horizontal scroll bar as a result. How do I fix this? I want everything in container-fluid to cover the entire width with no space on either side.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

container-fluid shouldn't give a padding. If you use container-fluid the whole container will go to full 100% width.

Are you sure that you dont have a class that gives the padding?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create any CSS in order to change Bootstrap padding (or margins). In your HTML the following will work.

You can use any number between 0 and 5 where 5 is the most amount of padding.

```
class="p-0" will create no padding at all.
class="px-0" will create no horizontal padding.
class="py-0" will create no vertical padding.
```

In addition.

```
class="pt-*" will change padding top.
class="pb-*" will change padding bottom.
class="ps-*" will change left side padding (padding-start).
class="pe-*" will change right side padding (padding-end).

* = insert number between 0 and 5
```

All of this works is you replace the `p` with an `m` if you want to change margins instead of padding.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out myself, so here's the solution. I worked it out by using Chrome devtools, opening the 'computed' window, clicking on the first element in the page and then pressing the down arrow util I saw what was causing the problem.

Every row has a default margin, so the solution is to add mx-0 to every row within your container, like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mx-0"></div>
  <div class="row mx-0"></div>
  <div class="row mx-0"></div>
</div>
```